# Initialize empty array of objects in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

I want to create an empty array object in react native that I want to populate with data from a sqlite table. I've searched on google but I only get responses like `this.state={}` or
`this.state = { newArr: [] }`, but I want to create an empty array of objects similar to
`const [{ID:'', Name:'', Email:''}]`.

any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, newArr=[] works. However if you want to make it something like that [{ID:'', Name:'', Email:''}]. It is also possible. Let me share some example.

```
const initialArr = [{ID:'', Name:'', Email:''}];
class YOURCOMPONENT extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
newArr:initialArr,
}
}
```